# Hiding Keyboard in Android

Tags: android, keyboard

I am new in Android application development, but I have programming knowledge in iOS. I have started to learn Andriod, yesterday only. I want to hide the keyboard when I click anywhere outside the EditText. But I found a code to hide the keyboard, which is following:

```
"InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtUserName.getWindowToken(), 0);"
```

Then I tried as following in my project, but I couldn't hide the keyboard.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    txtUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtUserName.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

My doubt is that do I need to add any touchEvents or keyboardEvents. Please help me.

Comment: If you want to go anywhere outside the EditText then press back button if the keyboard is open. You don't need to write code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is same as below see it may help you.

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-aOmfANlocYI/Tm9gJvI7s1I/AAAAAAAAAEA/yBEfcpoGX4U/s1600/3.JPG

make it right if it really helped you.

Comment: for more detail see: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2011/09/how-hide-keyboard-in-your-apps.html

Answer (score 2):

I did this in `onCreate()` and it helped:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 eidttext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!arg1) {
                hideKeyboard();

            }           

        }

        private void hideKeyboard() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(confpassword
                    .getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I have 2 questions regarding the above code snippet. 1. How do I tie the OnFocusChangeListener to my eidttext?

2. Where (specifically) does this code go in my activity? Inside my extends Activity...after the extends Activity...where oh where?

Comment: I have given the code as you provided, but its not getting hide. "txtUserName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean arg1) {
if (!arg1) { hideKeyboard();}}
private void hideKeyboard() {
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtUserName.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);}});" Do i missed out anything in the above code?

Comment: inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtUserName.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

Comment: Hi, I have given like that instead of O. Still no change.

Comment: Hi, I forget to tell one thing, I removed the @override Annotation from the code you provided. Because it's showing an error when i used it. Will that be the issue for not working. Following is the error showing : - implements android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener.onFocusChange
 - The method onFocusChange(View, boolean) of type new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){} must override a 
  superclass method

Comment: I got it worked, when i used setOnTouchListener instead of setOnFocusChangeListener. Then instead of EditText, I gave LinearLayout to capture the touch. thanks for your help. But I would like to know why focusChangeListener doesn't works. Can you help me for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for making sure the keyboard never shows up for an EditText box. You might be able to adapt it for your case.

```
protected void hideKeyboard(EditText et){
    et.setKeyListener(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
mInputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(zipCodeEdt.getWindowToken(), 0);
```